# Implementing fine-grain enabling/disabling of push notifications

Tags: android, ios, mobile, push-notification

Example of what I'm trying to implement: On the Facebook app, under notification settings, I can select to receive push-notifications for specific events, but not for others. I'm wondering what the recommended implementation approach here is, for both iOS and android apps.

Option 1: These user-selected notification settings are stored in a database, on the backend. Before sending any push notifications, we check the config in the database, and only send the push notifications if the user has not disabled it for that feature.

Option 2: The notification settings are stored only on the client-side. The backend will always send a push notification, using a specific "topic" for each feature. The client can then hide all notifications on a specific topic, if the user has disabled push-notifications for that feature.

Option 3: Something completely different that I'm not aware of?

How do most modern iOS/android apps implement this feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my 2 cents. I do this currently for a product which has Android, iOS and web implementations. We implemented **Option 1** and keep the filter settings for the user on server side. Here are few advantages I can think of right now.

**Advantage**:

- The first advantage is that we only need to implement the logic once instead of doing it at 3 places and thereby we only need to unit test at one place.
- If we need to change the logic, we need not make new Android/iOS builds and go through the app store release process for both Android and iOS again and again. This can take time as well.
- Although, there are no limits to sending the number of notifications from Google / Apple side but lets say there are hundreds's of thousands of notifications being sent out. Filtering on the server side will prevent the extra money being spent on your servers, who are doing the unnecessary extra work of continuously sending the messages which will eventually be ignored.

Comment: Few year back we had the same project request and we did **exactly** what @Shobhit Puri suggested. This way you're making future changes easy to implement (by adding/removing push notif. "filters") without compromising main server method that actually sends out notifications to APNS/GCM servers. Special +1 for the second bullet point !!

Answer (score 1):

This is simple but we can achieve into 2 way.

1) Send your push notification filter response to your server so based on userid and deviceid store those filter data into backend side and any notification generated time server first checked into its database and if filter option of any field is off then server is not sending notification and if true then server send notification to mobile.so this way we can achieve the one solution.

2) send your push notification filter response to your server to store into database and when user login into any device then pass this response as a details and store those details into local(sqlite) database or shared preference.Server will generate all the notification but as a programmatically first check those notification's value is true or false based on that we will generate notification.

Both the way are valid but i need to go for first one because server(backend) will handled all the things for us.

Hope this helps you.